# PPTP VPN on Android for Selected Apps

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, android, pptp

I've created a PPTP VPN on our firms Mikrotik router.
And I've successfully connected the android devices via their native VPN app in settings.

However that means that all of the traffic will be sent over the VPN. Which is something we don't want. We only want the Softphone app to work over the VPN with our phone server.

The only app I managed to find was OpenVpn, but that won't let me connect to PPTP I need a OpenVpn server. Which is something I don't want to do.

Can anyone recommend some app on android that will let me select the app I only want to use the VPN?

Comment: Doesn't Mikrotik let you choose what routes to push over the VPN? Instead of a default route, you can push just a few specific routes, e.g. for your IP addresses, or just a /32 for the phone server's IP.

Comment: Well everything goes over the PPTP. It has to be divided on the cell phone app side. Even if the Mikrotik could do that...it would take processing power, which is something I'm not willing to sacrifice.

Comment: You're missing the point entirely. Dividing traffic on the client side is _exactly what this would do_.

Comment: Okay. Well my phone server is setup on 10.0.0.120, after the client connects to the VPN the soft phone app is able to communicate with the server...therefore receive calls. What I want to achieve is to only use the VPN for voip. If you suggest I somehow split the traffic on the Mikrotiks end that'd be great cause it will solve my problem. I don't want the other traffic that falls outside the soft phone app to be transmitted through the VPN.

Answer (score 1):

When creating your VPN on Adnroid, you can choose which subnets will be using it. Check the "Show advanced options" in Android/VPN parameter screen and add the subnet you want to use with that VPN in the "Transfer route" field.

For example, let's say your App wants to connect to 10.0.0.120 via the VPN.

Set "10.0.0.0/24", or "10.0.0.120/32" in the "transfer route" field, and once connected, the phone will send traffic to that subnet via the PPTP link. Other traffic will use the regular phone gateway.